# How to create UISplitViewController programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, uisplitviewcontroller

Is there anyone who can help me to explain how to make UISpliterController programmatically in Swift. In my application I want to apply the supporting feature of iphone device and ipad. If the app is running on iphone then use single controler but if the application is running on ipad then use UISpliterController with existing ViewController.

I have tried it but it always produce blackscreen
Here is my code.

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

    let spliterVC = UISplitViewController()
    let homeNavControler = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeViewController") as! HomeViewController

    let secondVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    spliterVC.viewControllers = [homeNavControler,secondVC]
    appdelegate.window?.rootViewController = spliterVC
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want do it with navigationController, then try it:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        var splitViewController =  UISplitViewController()
        var homeViewController = HomeViewController()
        var secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        var homeNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:homeViewController)
        var secondNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:secondViewController)
        splitViewController.viewControllers = [homeNavigationController,secondNavigationController]
        self.window!.rootViewController = splitViewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    } else {
        // use single controller for iPhone and return that controller
    }
}
```